# Get immediate children from Postgres ltree path

Tags: postgresql, ltree

How do I get the immediate children from a given path in an `ltree` type in Postgres assuming the path always starts at root? For example if the given path is `A.B` and the column name of `ltree` is `path`, then the best I could come up with is:

`SELECT distinct(subpath(path, (SELECT distinct(nlevel('A.B'))), 1)) FROM test_ltree WHERE path ~ 'A.B.*{1,}';';`

Edit: I only want to return the children, without the parents in the path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be trivial:

```
TABLE ltree;

 id │  path   
════╪═════════
  1 │ A
  2 │ A.B
  3 │ A.B.C
  4 │ A.B.D
  5 │ A.B.D.E
  6 │ A.F
(6 rows)

SELECT * FROM ltree
WHERE path ~ 'A.B.*{1}'::lquery;

 id │ path  
════╪═══════
  3 │ A.B.C
  4 │ A.B.D
(2 rows)
```

The query finds all immediate children of `A.B`.

If you want to omit the `A.B` from the result, use `subpath` with a negative offset:

```
SELECT subpath(path, -1)
FROM ltree
WHERE path ~ 'A.B.*{1}'::lquery;

 subpath 
═════════
 C
 D
(2 rows)
```

To get only the next label after `A.B`, you could try

```
SELECT DISTINCT subpath(subpath(path, nlevel('A.B')), 0, 1)
FROM ltree
WHERE path ~ 'A.B.*{1,}'::lquery;
```

Comment: Right, but this includes the parents. I only want the immediate children without the parents in the return value.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. See my extended answer.

Comment: I think this still doesn't work as I expect to and I might've misled you by *{1}. I thought *{1} means return only the next label which is incorrect. It means only match paths that only has 1 more label. What I need is, given 'A.B', is ['C', 'D'] but 'D' here is from both id's 4 AND 5. But since 'D' is duplicate they are returned as a single element.

Comment: I think it'll be clear if we add another row | 7 | A.B.G.H. |. Now for 'A.B', the returned list should be [C,D,G]. C from id 3. D from both id's 4 & 5. G from id 7.

Comment: I have added another query.

Comment: Laurenz, what's the difference between what you have for the SELECT vs `SELECT DISTINCT subpath(name, nlevel('A.B'), 1)`? Yours tells Postgres to start looking after A.B while mine says start from A but gives an offset right? Since I have 1 less subpath() call would it be faster?

Comment: Your query looks more complicated to me, but I guess that the performance will be about the same. There is nothing wrong with your query.